# How to match substring from one file to another file using grep?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I have two files. File1 with bunch of email address. File2 with list of domains.

I want to find all the email address matching the domains (also the non-matching ones)

If some one please let me know how can we do this using 'grep' from terminal.

```
File1.csv
abc@gmail.com
abc@fmail.com
abc@fb.com
abc@hotmail.com
abc@outlook.com
abc@live.com

File2
hotmail.com
live.com
fb.com

The output should be (and non-matching as well)
abc@fb.com
abc@hotmail.com
abc@live.com

Please consider the email file is too big and contains 2M emails to compare against 6k domains.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -f to read the patterns from a file:

```
grep -f File2 File1.csv
```

Comment: will it match fixed pattern. I think this also match domain gmail.com with abc@1gmail.com?

Comment: You can add @ in front of every line in the patterns file to exclude @1gmail.com but that will not exclude gmail.com1 or gmail.com.ar and you can't use both regular expressions and patterns from a file at the same time with grep. You may need to write a script to archive more sophisticated filtering.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you are trying to match a fixed pattern of: `@[anydomainNameInFile2.txt]`

in this case, you might need to add  `@` at the beginning of each line in `File2` so you can use it as a fixed pattern.

you can do it by the following:

1. add `@` at the beginning of each line in file2.txt using
   `sed` command.

   ```
   $ sed 's/^/@/' file2.txt  > new-file.txt
   ```

don't worry that won't miss with your main file, you are saying it's about 2M field, we are saving the output to another file named `new-file.txt`

2. run the -f option grep command using the `new-file.txt` file as the following:

   ```
   $ grep -f newfile.txt File1.csv
   ```